# how to plot multiple charts using make_subplot in plotly and python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, subplot

I am trying to plot multiple charts using **plotly** and **make_subplot** where I want to plot 5 **pie charts** that are created using the iteration for loop. And 1 **bar chart** where the bar chart will take **colspan = 2**

## dataframe sample:

```
eventtype_name    date    eventmohafaza_name   number       groups
watch movie     8/14/2020   loc1                 25         group1
stay at home    8/13/2020   loc2                 20         group2
swimming        8/13/2020   loc2                 25         group4
camping         8/13/2020   loc3                 20         group3
meeting         8/13/2020   loc4                 40         group5
meeting         8/13/2020   loc5                 20         group2
watch movie     8/14/2020   loc4                 25         group1
stay at home    8/13/2020   loc1                 20         group2
swimming        8/13/2020   loc5                 25         group4
camping         8/13/2020   loc4                 20         group3
meeting         8/13/2020   loc3                 30         group5
meeting         8/13/2020   loc5                 33         group2
```

The problem is in when I assign the **rows** and **columns** and try to use **specs** parameter the system crash and display the below error.

```
This is the format of your plot grid:
[ (1,1)     ]  [ (1,2)     ]  [ (1,3)     ]
[ (2,1)     ]  [ (2,2)     ]  [ (2,3)     ]
[ (3,1)     ]  [ (3,2) x,y           -    ]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\plotly\subplots.py in _set_trace_grid_reference(trace, layout, grid_ref, row, col, secondary_y)
   1318     try:
-> 1319         subplot_refs = grid_ref[row - 1][col - 1]
   1320     except IndexError:

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-831d326e87b8> in <module>
     59                          rotation=90),
     60      row=row,
---> 61      col=col
     62     )
     63 

f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_trace(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1650             rows=[row] if row is not None else None,
   1651             cols=[col] if col is not None else None,
-> 1652             secondary_ys=[secondary_y] if secondary_y is not None else None,
   1653         )
   1654 

f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_traces(self, data, rows, cols, secondary_ys)
   1764         if rows is not None:
   1765             for trace, row, col, secondary_y in zip(data, rows, cols, secondary_ys):
-> 1766                 self._set_trace_grid_position(trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1767 
   1768         # Make deep copy of trace data (Optimize later if needed)

f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _set_trace_grid_position(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1847         grid_ref = self._validate_get_grid_ref()
   1848         return _set_trace_grid_reference(
-> 1849             trace, self.layout, grid_ref, row, col, secondary_y
   1850         )
   1851 

f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\plotly\subplots.py in _set_trace_grid_reference(trace, layout, grid_ref, row, col, secondary_y)
   1320     except IndexError:
   1321         raise Exception(
-> 1322             "The (row, col) pair sent is out of "
   1323             "range. Use Figure.print_grid to view the "
   1324             "subplot grid. "

Exception: The (row, col) pair sent is out of range. Use Figure.print_grid to view the subplot grid.
```

## code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_excel(file)
lst = list(df.groupby('eventmohafaza_name'))


rows = 3
cols = 3

subplot_titles = [l[0] for l in lst]


specs=[
           [{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"}],
           [{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"}],
           [{"type": "pie"},{"type": "bar",'colspan':2},None],
      ]

    
fig = make_subplots(
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        subplot_titles=subplot_titles,
        specs=specs,
        
        print_grid=True
)

for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    row = i // cols + 1
    col = i % (rows + 1) + 1
    d = l[1]
   
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=d["eventtype_name"],
                         values = d["number"],
                         hovertemplate = "%{label}: <br>Value: %{value} ",
                         showlegend=True,
                         textposition='inside',
                         rotation=90),
     row=row,
     col=col    
    )
    
group_event_groups = df.groupby([df['eventmohafaza_name'],df['eventtype_name']]).size().unstack()    
for x in group_event_groups.columns: 
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name=str(x), x=group_event_groups.index, y=group_event_groups[x],showlegend=False), row=3, col=2)
    
fig.update_layout(height = 1000,
                  width = 900,
                  autosize = False,
                  title="Population by Continent", 
                  title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

**the expected result is  5 pie charts and one bar chart**

Comment: I can't see the data at hand as it's not presented, but I don't need the comma at the end of the list that I'm setting in 'specs='. Isn't that affecting you?

Comment: i removed the comma but it still the same problem  i edit my question and added the dataframe sample

Comment: There are not enough attributes in the test data to represent the number of graphs. Is there a problem with the calculation logic of row,col in the n-loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added new attribute data to the sample data and modified the calculation logic for rows and cols. Also, the last bar graph is now a single graph because the number of graphs does not match the looped data.

```
lst = list(df.groupby('eventmohafaza_name'))

rows = 3
cols = 3

subplot_titles = [l[0] for l in lst]

specs=[[{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"}],
       [{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"},{"type": "pie"}],
       [{"type": "pie"},{"type": "bar",'colspan':2},None]]

fig = make_subplots(
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        subplot_titles=subplot_titles,
        specs=specs,  
        print_grid=True
)

for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    row = i // cols + 1
    col = (i % rows) + 1
    d = l[1]
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=d["eventtype_name"],
                         values = d["number"],
                         hovertemplate = "%{label}: <br>Value: %{value} ",
                         showlegend=True,
                         textposition='inside',
                         rotation=90),
     row=row,
     col=col    
    )
    
group_event_groups = df.groupby([df['eventmohafaza_name'],df['eventtype_name']]).size().unstack()    
# for x in group_event_groups.columns: 
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='camping', x=group_event_groups.index, y=group_event_groups.columns, showlegend=False), row=3, col=2)
    
fig.update_layout(height = 1000,
                  width = 900,
                  autosize = False,
                  title="Population by Continent", 
                  title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what if i want to make the **specs**  flexible like so :

`rows = 3
  cols = 3 
  specs = [[{"type": "pie"}]* cols * rows ,[{"type": "bar"}]]` 

is this right  ?

Comment: In the example shown in the comments, the graph has nine columns and two rows.
The matrix structure and the specs list structure need to match.

Comment: so if i understand your comment right 
if i assign row and col like so :
`tl = pd.unique(df['eventtype_name'].tolist())
lst = list(df.groupby('eventmohafaza_name'))

rows = len(lst)
cols = len(tl)`

the specs parameter will work?

Comment: In the previous comment, a 5x5 graph? As a simple example, in a two-line, two-column graph, specs=[[GraphA,GraphB]],[GraphC,GraphD]], resulting in a multiple list.

Comment: can you explain more your last comment because i did not understand .
let say i have i have a **rows = 5  and cols = 3**
if i try to write the code of rows and specs how should i wrote it ??

`rows = 5 # len (lst)
cols = 3 # int(len(tl)/2)
specs = [[{"type": "pie"}]* cols * rows ,[{"type": "bar"}]]`
the system crash and dsiplay:
`ValueError: 
The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (5 x 3).
    Received value of type <class 'list'>: [[{'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'pie'}, {'type': 'pie'},....], [{'type': 'bar'}]]`

Comment: If you write it in code, it looks like this But for one type. `rows=5;cols=3;specs =[[{'type':'pie'}]*cols]*rows`

Comment: so it can't be used more than one type

Comment: `specs[4] = [{'type': 'pie'},{'type': 'pie'},{'type': 'bar'}] `Then the last graph would be a bar chart.